# Getting all web services and database connections from QGIS in PyQGIS?

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pyqgis-3

I need to write a plugin for QGIS but I am not very familiar with QGIS itself and kind of new to all of this.

I want to get all connections programmatically. By connections I mean everything from WMS to WFS to PostGIS.

I have discovered that those connections are stored in the `QGIS3.ini` but have not yet found a way in Python to get this data (except for scanning trough the file for the information, but surely there most be a better way).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needn't to scan ini file for connection, you can directly connect to a WMS/WFS/PostGIS service. Here is a WMS sample. Copy the following code to the QGIS Python console:

```
url="url=http://www.agt.bme.hu:80/cgi-bin/bme.wms&format=image/png&layers=bme2c&styles=&crs=EPSG:23700"
rlayer=QgsRasterLayer(url, 'topo', 'wms')
if rlayer.isValid():
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(rlayer)
else:
    print("error")
```

It is similar for WFS but you have to use QgsVectorLayer(url, "name", "WFS") and of course the url must be a valid link to a WFS server. For PostGIS layer you can find samples in PyQGIS docs: https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/loadlayer.html

UPDATE

Reacting to comment from @brezzOr. 
Reading the ini file using configparser Python modeule is not a nigthmare. Here is an example to list all wms connections:

```
import configparser
import re

ini_path = '/home/siki/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/QGIS/QGIS3.ini'
parser = configparser.ConfigParser()

parser.read(ini_path)

wms = re.compile('^connections-wms.*url$')

print(parser.sections())
for key in parser['qgis']:
    if wms.search(key):
        print(parser['qgis'][key])
```

Correct the ini_path to fit your user name and OS.

Comment: I might need to clarify, I do not want to connect to a wms (at this point), I just want to get all services that are available in the current profile without scanning the ini file for it.

Comment: I updated my answer.

Comment: that is perfect, I hoped there would be a way around this because I expected to regex the whole thing would be painful. But that looks very easy. Im new to python so thanks a lot.